# moving and resize image canvas object in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want move and resize tkinter canvas image object.
It works well moveing image.
but resizing image using bind or button is error. help me.
maybe, I don't know well command function(argument) of bind and button.
who explain me easy by sample code.. 
and my english is bad..

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import os
import PIL.Image

def  move_rectangular(event):
    if event.keysym == 'Up':
        canvas.move(object_1, 0, -3)
      #  canvas.move(object_2, 0, -3)
    if event.keysym == 'Down':
        canvas.move(object_1, 0, 3)
      #  canvas.move(object_2, 0, 3)   
    if event.keysym == 'Left':
        canvas.move(object_1, -3, 0)
     #   canvas.move(object_2, -3, 0)  
    if event.keysym == 'Right':
        canvas.move(object_1, 3, 0)
    #    canvas.move(object_2, 3, 0)
def  size_change(event, obj, img):    
    if event.keysym == 'b':        
        width = img.width
        height = img.height
        w = width+10
        h = height+10
        canvas.config(obj,width=w, height=h)

    if event.keysym == 's':        
        width = img.width
        height = img.height
        w = width-10
        h = height-10
        canvas.config(obj,width=w, height=h)

def size_down(obj,img):
        width = img.width
        height = img.height
        w = width-10
        h = height-10
        canvas.config(obj,width=w, height=h)
def size_up(obj,img):
        width = img.width
        height = img.height
        w = width+10
        h = height+10
        canvas.config(obj,width=w, height=h)

tk = Tk()
tk.geometry("1400x1200")
tk.title("move,resize")
mainMenu = Menu(tk)
tk.config(menu=mainMenu)


canvas = Canvas(tk, width=1300, height=853)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=E)

img = Image.open(os.getcwd() + '/rectangular.jpg')
photo3 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
object_1 = canvas.create_image(300,220, anchor=NW, image=photo3)

canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Up>', move_rectangular)
canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Down>', move_rectangular)
canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Left>', move_rectangular)
canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Right>', move_rectangular)
# canvas bind size change
canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-s>', lambda event, a=object_1, b=img: size_change(a, b))
canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-b>', lambda event, a=object_1, b=img: size_change(a, b))

#button canvas size change
btn = Button(tk, text="size-", command=lambda:size_down(object_1,img))
btn.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=N)
btn = Button(tk, text="size+", command=lambda:size_up(object_1,img))
btn.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=N)

tk.mainloop()
```

> _cnfmerge: fallback due to: 'int' object is not iterable Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 107, in _cnfmerge
>       cnf.update(c) TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1482, in **call**
>       return self.func(*args)   File "D:/test/move,resize.py", line 70, in 
>       btn = Button(tk, text="size-", command=lambda:size_down(object_1,img))   File
>   "D:/test/move,resize.py", line 39, in size_down
>       canvas.config(obj,width=w, height=h)   File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1270, in configure
>       return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)   File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1254, in _configure
>       cnf = _cnfmerge((cnf, kw))   File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 110, in _cnfmerge
>       for k, v in c.items(): AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'items'
>   _cnfmerge: fallback due to: 'int' object is not iterable Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 107, in _cnfmerge
>       cnf.update(c) TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1482, in **call**
>       return self.func(*args)   File "D:/test/move,resize.py", line 72, in 
>       btn = Button(tk, text="size+", command=lambda:size_up(object_1,img))   File "D:/test/move,resize.py",
>   line 45, in size_up
>       canvas.config(obj,width=w, height=h)   File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1270, in configure
>       return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)   File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1254, in _configure
>       cnf = _cnfmerge((cnf, kw))   File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 110, in _cnfmerge
>       for k, v in c.items(): AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'items' Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1482,
>   in **call**
>       return self.func(*args)   File "D:/test/move,resize.py", line 66, in 
>       canvas.bind_all('', lambda event, a=object_1, b=img: size_change(a, b)) TypeError: size_change() missing 1 required
>   positional argument: 'img' Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback
>   (most recent call last):   File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter__init__.py",
>   line 1482, in **call**
>       return self.func(*args)   File "D:/test/move,resize.py", line 67, in 
>       canvas.bind_all('', lambda event, a=object_1, b=img: size_change(a, b)) TypeError: size_change() missing 1 required
>   positional argument: 'img'

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @Bryan Oakley I list up again

Comment: The error is telling you what the problem is: "size_change() missing 1 required positional argument: 'img'" You've defined `size_change` to take three parameters, you are only giving it two.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley yeah I know..